# Flutter getx: How to send data between pages from FirestoreQueryBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, get

I'd Like to get data in home screen of my flutter app, where I have list of OfferCards, these are generated from firestore via FirestoreQueryBuilder in my homeView like this

```
FirestoreQueryBuilder<OfferData>(
          pageSize: 10,
          query: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('Offers')
              .orderBy('CreatedAt', descending: true)
              .withConverter<OfferData>(
                  fromFirestore: ((snapshot, options) =>
                      OfferData.fromJson(snapshot.data()!)),
                  toFirestore: (value, options) => value.toJson()),
          builder: (context, snapshot, _) {
            if (snapshot.isFetching) {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.greenAccent),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Center(
                child: Text('Server error'),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.docs.isEmpty) {
              return const Center(
                child: Text('No offers'),
              );
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final hasReachEnd = snapshot.hasMore &&
                        index + 1 == snapshot.docs.length &&
                        !snapshot.isFetchingMore;

                    if (hasReachEnd) {
                      snapshot.fetchMore();
                    }
                    final post = snapshot.docs[index].data();
                    homeController.offers[index] = post;
                    return OfferCardView();
                  },
                  itemCount: snapshot.docs.length);
            }
          },
        )
```

As on the end of this example, inside HomeController I have Map of int and UserData, which is filled with all offers. Each offerCardView has Get.find to HomeController to have access to this map. And here's my question, how do I determine inside of OfferCardView and later in OfferView(after tapping on given OfferCardView) which entry from map is being clicked on/view filled with. I don't know how to acomplish this, I'm aware that using Map here is bad decision, but I don't have clue how this should be done

Comment: do you mean that you want when you tap in any `OfferCardView` widgets, it opens the OfferView with it's document data ?

Comment: @Gwhyyy exactly, this is how HomeView looks like https://imgur.com/a/u3V8avF
and each of this entry is idividual OfferCardView, which after tapping on takes us to OfferView with same data but on whole screen with other layout. Is this possible to have this one data collection from FirestoreQueryBuilder gathered inside of HomeView and pass it to other Pages, or I  just have to redownload this  data again from firestore on every OfferView entry?

Comment: Can you clarify this "but on whole screen with other layout", do you mean just that the document data should be different based on each OfferCardView, what do you mean with "other layout"

Comment: you can pass each document data with it's index to the OfferView constructor, so for every OfferCardView that will be clicked, OfferView will be opened with it's data

Comment: if thsi exactly what you want, I will be happy to write a full answer for it

Comment: This is how it was done before with passing each document to OfferCardView and then from it via navigator and OfferView constructor. Now I'm rewriting this app to getx and I thought it would be bad practice to pass data through page contrustor. But this seem as something that may satisfy me, you can post full answer

Comment: I actually kinda understood what you want, but I would say that the safest way to pass data is via the constructor, since depending on GetxController to exchange data like this could simply break up. For example, if you're app grows and somewhere you needed to delete the controller, then `Get.find()` will not find that controller, and your app will just break, then you need to find where did it go wrong.

Comment: you need just to modelize your data into a class model, then play with it as you want.

Comment: Okay, but if I have AppPages class with all my GetPage routes and code there like this
  ` GetPage(
      name: _Paths.OFFER_CARD,
      page: () =>  OfferCardView(),
      binding: OfferCardBinding(),
    ),`

It gives me error that OfferCardView needs an OfferData parameter there, and I can't pass null. What;s best practise to solve this?

Comment: I suggest you to to make a placeholder model by default where we like to say 'there is data that inform that there is no data so we showed you that page with this data'. I guess it's a good practice for the user exeperience.

Comment: Works well, thanks. I guess that's it for now, I thought that passing models through arguments is bad practice with Get, but it seem as reasonable solution, Please post it as full answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better practice is passing each document data with its `index` to the `OfferView()` constructor, so for every `OfferCardView()` that will be clicked, `OfferView()` will be opened with that data.

This ensures that your data will not rely on the `GetxController` availability, since depending on `GetxController` to exchange data like this could simply break.

For example :

While your app is growing and somewhere the controller is deleted either by `Getx` or manually using `Get.delete()` ( or you needed to call multiple controllers with different tags ), then `Get.find()` will not find that controller or mistake it, this leads to unexpected behaviors, which will put you in a hard time to find out what went wrong in your project.

Using `GetPage`, if you're required to assign the model data property, you could make a placeholder model for that data by default where we would say like :

> There is no data so we showed you that placeholder alternative data page with this data.

This gives the user at least an overview of what's happening, not just a direct crash for the app.

I would say it's a good practice for the user experience.

Comment: Instead of index I used arguments in Get.to route with OfferModel passed instead as class argument, and looks more convenient in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

You can share variables from other controllers onto another controller by using GetX Dependency Injection

On binding , add the controller you want to add as a dependency

```
Get.lazyPut<OfferCardsController>(() => OfferCardsController());
```

then in the controller

```
var offerCardsController = Get.find<OfferCardsController>();
```

you can now access variables from the `OfferCardsController` on`OfferController`

e.g

```
offerCardsController.variableFromCardsController;
```